# Executing code while waiting for a timeout

Tags: javascript

I want to create a *localstorage object* before some time has elapsed and destroy it after a certain time has elapsed. I plan on using the setTimeout method:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    localStorage.setItem("myobject", "wedding");
}, 20000);
```

I want to use an if statement to try and do that:

```
var notYetTimeout;    
if (notYetTimeout) {
    //create the object before 20000 ms have elapsed
    localStorage.setItem("myobject", "wedding");
} else {
    //destroy object after 2000ms have elapsed
    localStorage.removeItem("myobject");
}
```

The code just shows you a rough idea and I want to know if this is possible in javascript?

Comment: Wouldn't you just store it *now*, and then remove it in a timeout ?

Comment: Executing the code when waiting is important in what i am trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure I get it, waiting for what? `setTimeout` is async?

Comment: Can't get a grip on your example: "create the object before 2000ms" (so from _now_ to _2sec_). "destroy object after 200ms". Meaning 0.2sec after creation I assume?

Comment: Yes,destryoy it 20000ms which is 20 secs after creation.

Comment: That's not at all what your example shows. Very confusing.

Comment: Its okay,i am trying to simulate lag,i guess it can't the way i was hoping it would. I am trying to have such a function on the client side `Meteor._sleepForMs`. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand the timings in your example, but hopefully you can get some use of the below example:

This will call setStorage after 1 sec and then call remStorage 3 sec after that.

```js
function setStorage(key, val) {
  //localStorage.setItem(key, val);
  console.log('set storage ' + key);
  setTimeout(function() {
    remStorage('myobject');
  }, 3000);
}

function remStorage(key) {
  //localStorage.removeItem(key);
  console.log('removed storage ' + key);
}

setTimeout(function() {
  setStorage('myobject', 'wedding');
}, 1000);
```